# Flutter Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to run flutter project on my phone but I get this exception:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.3/gradle-4.1.3.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.3/gradle-4.1.3.jar
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.3/gradle-4.1.3.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.3/gradle-4.1.3.jar
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps:

1. Delete the android directory.
2. Run `flutter clean` comment
3. Run `flutter create .` comment
4. Run `flutter pub get` comment
5. Run the application.